# Copying data from one dataframe to another with different column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], columns=list('ABCDE'))
```

I need to create another dataframe by copying data from df in this format:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 0], [ 3, 4, 5], [ 6, 7, 0], [ 8, 9, 10]], columns=list('PQR'))
```

I've tried append and concat, but mainly facing an issue due to the column names being different.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

reshaping ur data requires getting the first two columns and concatenating with the last three columns :

```
a = df.iloc[:,:2].set_axis([ent for ent,_ in enumerate(a.columns)],axis=1)
a

    0   1
0   1   2
1   6   7

b = df.iloc[:,2:].set_axis([ent for ent,_ in enumerate(b.columns)],axis=1)
b

    0   1   2
0   3   4   5
1   8   9   10

res = pd.concat((a,b)).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index(drop=True)
res


    0   1   2
0   1   2   0
1   6   7   0
2   3   4   5
3   8   9   10
```

Comment: Thanks! this solves part of the issue. What if I want to ignore the column names? I am basically trying to breakdown a row with 360 values into 6 rows, where 3 rows have 48 values and 3 rows of 72. Basically, writing a string with 48 column names is a bit tedious. Considering renaming the columns to numeric values and then changing the column names in the final dataframe. That's a rather ugly solution though.

Comment: So, if it were possible to the exact same thing, just without the set_axis part, I think it would be perfect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the update. But i think the previous solution is a little better for what i intend to do.